# Laravel groupBy on relationship without array_merge

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a Laravel 9 project. I've created a `Product` model and `ProductOption` model. My options need to be grouped by a column called `region_code` *(which isn't always set)* so that the options for the product can easily be shown. I realise that if I run `$product->options->groupBy('region_code')` it will give me the desired result, but I need these grouped options to be part of the `Product` model, thus I'm doing an `array_merge`.

This approach works, but I feel that it's a bit messy having to convert it to an array and merging the results back into one.

I did try doing a `groupBy('region_code')` in my `with` clause, but this didn't give me anything.

Here's my current code and output

```php
$selectedProduct = $request->input('product');
$selectedType = $request->input('type');

$product = Product::where('slug', $selectedProduct)
->where('is_enabled', true)
->with(['options' => function ($query) use ($selectedType) {
    $query->where('is_enabled', true)
          ->whereNotNull('region_code')
          ->where('slug', 'like', "%$selectedType%");
}])->first();

if (! $product) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => "No product found."
    ], 404);
}

$product = array_merge($product->toArray(), [
    'options' => $product->options->groupBy('region_code')->toArray()
]);

return response()->json([
    'product' => $product
], 200);
```

[image]

A cleaner approach I thought I could override the `options` key, and do this:

```
$options = $product->options->groupBy('region_code');
$product->options = $options;

return response()->json([
    'product' => $product
], 200);
```

But this then looses the grouping entirely.

How could I clean this up?

#### UPDATE

Below is my table schema for each model:

`Product`

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->json('extra')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('is_enabled')->default(1)->index();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

`ProductOption`

```php
Schema::create('product_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->foreignUuid('product_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->string('region_code')->nullable()->index();
    $table->json('extra')->nullable();
    $table->string('stripe_id')->unique();
    $table->integer('quantity')->default(1);
    $table->boolean('is_enabled')->default(1)->index();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

[image]

Comment: So the result you are looking for is **$product->options->aso** will return an array of ProductOption that is grouped by it?

Answer (score -1):

```
$selectedProduct = $request->input('product');
$selectedType = $request->input('type');

$product = Product::where('slug', $selectedProduct)
    ->where('is_enabled', true)
    ->with(['options' => function ($query) use ($selectedType) {
        $query->where('is_enabled', true)
            ->whereNotNull('region_code')
            ->where('slug', 'like', "%$selectedType%")
            

             //just add here
            ->groupBy('region_code');


    }])->first();

if (!$product) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => "No product found."
    ], 404);
}

return response()->json([
    'product' => $product
], 200);
```

Comment: This produces an error. Strange. It's what I thought might've worked, the error I get is: `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'snapisms_db.product_options.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: I have use this solution many time its working fine for me. So show me your both tables structure / schema for correct solution.

Comment: I've provided the schema for each model as an update.